# How to ensure method called with subclass param work with generic Class object?

Tags: java, generic-programming

For example, I got 3 classes:

Superclass: `Animal`

Subclass extend Superclass: `Cat`, `Tiger`.

I Wrote a checker class, `AnimalChecker` to distinguish the type of animal, and make each type call different method(different type of param, same method name).
If using C++ template, it is possible to do this kind of work, wonder to know is their simple way to make it work with **Java**, I did some tries but not get it yet.
:

> `AnimalChecker` defined below:

```
public abstract class AnimalChecker {
    private List<Class<? extends Animal>> mAnimals;
    public AnimalChecker(Class<? extends Animal>... animals) {
        mAnimals = Arrays.asList(animals);
    }
    public boolean CheckAnimal(Animal animal) {
        Iterator<Class<? extends Animal>> it = mAnimals.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Class clazz = it.next();
            if (clazz.isInstance(animal)) {
                onCheck(animal, clazz);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public abstract void onCheck(Animal animal, Class<? extends Animal> clazz);
}
```

> Then I tried implement the class, do the specific work for each type:

```
public class Main {
    public static MyChecker msChecker = new MyChecker();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnimalChecker checker = new AnimalChecker(Cat.class, Tiger.class) {
            @Override
            public void onCheck(Animal animal, Class<? extends Animal> clazz) {
                System.out.println(clazz.toGenericString());
                msChecker.onCheck(clazz.cast(animal));
            }
        };
        checker.CheckAnimal(new Tiger());
        checker.CheckAnimal(new Cat());

        MyChecker myChecker = new MyChecker();
        myChecker.onCheck(new Tiger());
        myChecker.onCheck(new Cat());
    }

    static class MyChecker {
        public void onCheck(Animal animal) {
            System.out.println("Animal");
        }
        public void onCheck(Cat animal) {
            System.out.println("Cat");
        }
        public void onCheck(Tiger animal) {
            System.out.println("Tiger");
        }
    }
}
```

> The output below isn't what I want:

```
public class test.Tiger
Animal
public class test.Cat
Animal
Tiger
Cat
```

> I wanna to make the result

```
public class test.Tiger
Tiger
public class test.Cat
Cat
Tiger
Cat
```

Comment: can you explain your desired output??

Answer (score 2):

Java will not do this for you, quite simply. What you are trying to make Java do is called [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch), and Java does not support it. The types of method arguments are only matched against argument values at compile-time, by the compiler, not at runtime. In your code, the most specific thing the compiler knows about your argument value is that it is of type `Animal`, and therefore it chooses to link to that method. The `clazz.cast()` call doesn't help, since the same argument applies to the `clazz` variable: the most specific thing the compiler knows about it is that it is `? extends Animal`, and therefore the result of the `cast()` call is of type `Animal` as far as the compiler is concerned.

There are, of course, ways for you to achieve similar effects in Java, but I don't think I can choose one for you. There is one example in the above linked Wikipedia article on multiple dispatch, and you may also want to consider something akin to the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), but don't feel bound by patterns. :)

Comment: Thank you for taught me the `multiple dispatch` concept!